# How to run certain Selenium commands based on the URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the Java Language Binding with ChromeDriver as my browser.

I am creating a Selenium script that relies on very similar URL's. However, the elements on the pages are different depending on the URLs. I would like to run one set of commands if the URL is 'www.genericwebsiteA.com'. If the URL is 'www.genericwebsiteB.com' I would like a different set of instructions to run.

I have managed to get both scripts working individually as their own Selenium scripts does anyone have any possible solutions to this. I can't seem to find out how to implement an if statement to see which set of instructions my webdriver should follow.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using `driver.getCurrentUrl()`:

```
String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
if (currentURL.contains("www.genericwebsiteA.com")) {
    // run tests for A
} else if (currentURL.contains("www.genericwebsiteB.com")) {
    // run tests for B
}
```